# How to download all type File in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am using the Yii framework basic and I have the website to allow the admin to upload a text file and I need to download file from my folder, but I am unable to download.

My controller action is

```
  public function actionDownload(){
     $url= $_GET["url"];
  $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . "/$url";

   $file = $path;

   if (file_exists($file)) {

   Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
                     }
    }
```

my view is

```
<a href="download?url=download/notes/trIssues5850f5ae5cd6.docx">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

If I click download it just read the content of the file and display straight in the page. What I want to do is when users click the download link, the download dialog will pop up or the file will be automatically downloaded, rather than display the content.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of :

```
sendFile($file);
```

Try this :

```
xSendFile($file)
```